# Facebook URL share option, doesn't support gif image while the same option works in giphy.com

Tags: facebook, animated-gif, facebook-sharer

Even though exact meta tags are used, the shared url doesn't scrape correctly, the gif isn't shown, while in giphy.com's facebook share option returns the expected result. Is there a some sort of agreement with facebook?

Comment: I would try and explain further what you are seeing on both sites, with actual URLs or examples, it is not clear what you're trying to fix/error you see.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but i was able to find the solution, look below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved, I was able to share GIF with facebook sharer. For example, the link is the following, https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com/gif. So in my application when facebook's bot tries to enter my link - http://example.com/gif I'm just returning the gif image by WRITING it directly to the output stream. If you return the actual gif url or feed regurl og:image metatags it WILL NOT work. So the secret is to write the gif directly to the output stream. The following is the java code how to handle it:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/gif", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "image/gif")
public void testphoto(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    URL imageURL = new URL("http://example.com/some_real_gif_url.gif");
    final String formatName = "gif";
    response.setContentType("image/gif");

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = imageURL.openStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count;

    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    // Flush out stream, to write any remaining buffered data
    out.flush();

}
```

If implemented correctly, you will get the same result as giphy share option offer in the following link - https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://gph.is/YeaoHh